# Stuck in weird issue with nginx reverse proxy - need help pls

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am stuck in this weird issue. I have nginx as my reverse proxy set in front of Apache web server Some how my proxy_pass is not working as expected and getting 404 not found error while retrieving page. Can someone pls help?

```
Reve Proxy IP - 10.122.0.4
Apache 10.122.0.3
```

On my Rev Proxy /etc/hosts file
10.122.0.3 ipbl.xxxx.xxx

Here is my nginx stanza

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name threat.list.xxx.xxx;
# return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
modsecurity on;
modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;
error_page 404 403 /custom_404.html;
location = /custom_404.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
internal;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/threatlist/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/threatlist/error.log;
location / {
if ($request_method !~ "GET") {
return 403;
break;
}
include /etc/nginx/threatlistacl/ipacls;
deny all;
client_max_body_size 10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
proxy_read_timeout 90;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
proxy_pass http://ipbl.xxxx.xxxx;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

Now if I access ipbl.xxx.xxx/ipbl.txt page it gets accessed successfully

```
Request URL: http://threat.list.xxx.xxx/ipbl.txt
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: xxx.xx.xx.xx:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Sat, 13 Mar 2021 04:50:53 GMT
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: threat.list.xxx.xxx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36
```

And my access.log

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [13/Mar/2021:10:31:17 +0530] "GET /ipbl.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 183 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Now this is really weird. I reverified and found that access logs are being generated on my backend webs server in default access.log. That means requests are being sent to default vhost on apache2 server.

Comment: Check about how many blocks handling the port 80, sometimes default servers get in between and capture the request. Best is not to use default config

Answer (score 0):

I posted my virtualhost config in apache2.conf and deleted my ipbl.conf file from sites-enabled somehow that worked. Plus I added entries in /etc/hosts [not sure if this is required to match ServerName]